# DAX Measure PowerPivot: Exclude groups based on subgroup values

Tags: dax, measure

I am trying to create a measure based on summarizing variables (such as the average "Grams of Material") by Production Group (see data example below).

[image: Sample Data]

Production Groups contain Products, identified by the Product ID field.  When that Product is finished being produced, it is marked as "Complete" and the "Grams of Material" are entered.

I am able to use the `GROUPBY` and `SUMX`, `AVERAGEX`, `CALCULATE` and `FILTER` functions to summarize by groups and exclude certain rows.  However, I do NOT want to summarize any Production Groups that include **Incomplete** Products.

For instance, in the sample data below, I would not want to see any reporting on Production Group B, as some Products within that group are "Incomplete".

Please let me know how you might accomplish this.

Here is some sample code that summarizes by the group I want, but does not exclude the groups with incomplete products.

```
    averagex(  
        GROUPBY(Table,[Production Group],"Production Group Yield", 
        SUMX(CURRENTGROUP(),[Grams Material])),[Production Group Yield])
```

Best,

ML

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this very differently.

```
VAR Groups = VALUES ( 'Table'[Production Group] ) // all groups in context
VAR GroupsWithIncomplete =
  CALCULATETABLE (
    VALUES ( 'Table'[Production Group] ),
    'Table'[Processing Complete?] = "Incomplete"
  )
VAR GroupsWithoutIncomplete =
  EXCEPT ( Groups, GroupWithIncomplete ) // just a set difference
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Value] ),
    GroupsWithoutIncomplete
  )
    / COUNTROWS ( GroupsWithoutIncomplete )
```

We can easily get a set of all groups in context, with `VALUES`. Then we find all groups in context that have an Incomplete. The set difference leaves us with only the groups in context without an incomplete. We can use that set as a filter to `CALCULATE` and the denominator for the average here is simply the number of groups in the set `GroupsWithoutIncomplete`.